# Dockers Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code on redhat linux

Tags: docker

I installed Docker on redhat linux and trying to change the docker0 network ip to 10.10.10.10/24. For that i am following the link https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/powermeup/entry/Setting_up_a_Docker_Bridge?lang=en. Now i facing issue `Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` while starting the docker.service.

Could anybody suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you included in the question exactly what you changed and the output of the two commands mentioned in the error messages.

Comment: Hello David Maze, Here is the output of systemctl status docker.service:  `docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2019-01-22 16:38:49 EST; 15h ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 530 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -b=br0 -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) Main PID: 530 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

Comment: and i did the changes in docker.service as `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -b=br0 -H fd:// `. After that i reloaded the daemon and started the docker service. while i am checking the docker status i getting the error as mentioned in the  above comment.